# Jar is being loaded by JVM from cache even there is difference(jar is updated)

Tags: java, caching, jar, jvm, applet

I have some jars being used in archive tag of my applet. While opening the applet, jars are being loaded fine. Recently I found that the jar is being loaded from cache even the jar is updated on the server.

I didn't use "cache_archive" attribute for that jar, but still it is loading from cache. Is it default behavior of JVM to load jar from java cache even it is updated on server?

If so, how to avoid it. I couldn't find any pointer for that when googled.

My requirement is to load jar from server if jar is updated. Otherwise from cache.

I know that we can avoid loading jar from cache using below tag, but that is not my requirement:

`<param name="cache_option" value="no">`

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but keep in mind that applets are deprecated.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. you may be worrying about the wrong thing. How old is this applet?

Comment: Yes I know applets are deprecated but my application is huge and old. I can't write all the code again. I need suggestions on my requirement above. Thanks for understanding.